# Is there an alternative to the autocomplete="off" attribute that’s valid XHTML Strict?

Tags: html, autocomplete

I have an XHTML 1.0 Strict document with an input field with `autocomplete='off'`. The w3c validator tells me that in strict documents you may not use autocomplete. So is there an alternative without changing the document type?

Comment: possible duplicate of [autocomplete attribute is not passing XHTML 1.0 Transitional validation, why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516364/autocomplete-attribute-is-not-passing-xhtml-1-0-transitional-validation-why)

Comment: Oh, I didnt find this question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

No. XHTML 1.0 provides no means to tell browsers not to help users fill in form fields.

Comment: … or you could stop telling browsers not to be helpful.

Comment: @phpheini: out of interest, what’s the problem with changing the doctype?

Comment: @Paul D. Waite: Im kind of scared of changing it ;) cos I dont know what will happen and if everything will be all messed up and all the special characters will be destroyed.

Comment: @ David Dorward: I dont think thats a solution. I have a search field with ajax which gives the user possible search examples. Without autocomplete='off' the browser will show his suggestions on top of my ajax suggestions so you cant see them anymore.

Comment: By the way: Is there any advantage of using strict? I can imagine that Google likes websites with strict more cos they are very valid?

Comment: Strict doesn't have crap you shouldn't use (there is a strong, but not prefect, correlation between "Stuff only in Transitional" and "Stuff that is deprecated" and "Stuff you should do with CSS"). Transitional does **not** include the autocomplete attribute.

Comment: I dont see why autocomplete is considered as crap? How would you rather do a suggest-script with ajax without browser suggestions?

Comment: Stuff only in transitional considered crap. Autocomplete **not** (repeat **not!!**) in transitional. Therefore autocomplete considered crap? There's a logic failure there.

Comment: @phpheini: sure, I can see changing the doctype is a risk. It shouldn’t affect any special characters you’re using (that’s related to charset rather than doctype), but you might get some different validation errors (e.g. relating to elements/attributes that were left out of HTML5). I’m not sure if the deprecated stuff in HTML Transitional is worth worrying about now that HTML5 is the future. If it’s in HTML5, I think it’s looking likely to stay for a while. E.g. `s` was deprecated in HTML 4, but is in HTML5.

Comment: Thanks 4 your answer. So what kind of doctype would you change it then?

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript. Write a little function that clears all of the input fields in a form by settings there value to an empty string. On page load, call the function, but call it in a setTimeout of about a second or so. If a value has been automatically entered into a field by the browser, it will be wiped by the javascript. The only problem with this is that the autocomplete value may be temporarily visible in the field before it is replaced.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue simply by using jquery

```
//Try this one:

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("input.autocompleteOff").attr("autocomplete","off");
    });

//For all textbox -

    $(document).ready(function(){$("input").attr("autocomplete","off");});

//HTML

<input type="text" name="field" id="field" class="autocompleteOff" />
```

Comment: in my opinion, invalid HTML is better than HTML which becomes invalid after it becomes validated. I think the OP should either use a different doctype or ignore the validators suggestion

Comment: Where does the browser complete the fields, in the timeline?  This approach will only work if the browser autocomplete happens **after** dom ready - is that definitely the case in all browsers that have this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

How about putting a hidden and fake password field like

```
<input type="password" name="stupid_autofill" id="stupid_autofill" value="" style="display:none;">
```

before the real password field. This generally works on the basis of the browser trying to guess the input field before the password field.

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution in this latest version is put on the input
`autocomplete = 'false'`.